# Do kidnappers only kidnap kids?

Tags: word-usage

As I read at http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kidnap, the etymology for *kidnap* is

> kid (“child”) + nap (“nab, grab”)

Can an adult person also be kidnapped? Would it sound funny to say so? The definition mentions *person*, not *child*, but I'm not sure. (In my language we have a borrowed word *kidnapper*, but I only heard it referring to someone who abducted children or house pets, probably because the users of the word recognised the *kid* stem in it.)

Comment: just to add to the answers; kidnap would more strongly suggest a ransom, whereas abduct might not. The distinction is not absolute, though.

Comment: And here I was, thinking that "kidnappers" are people who force kids to take a nap...

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/60898/24041

Comment: And you can use "spirited away" for a kidnapping with religious connotation.

Comment: @Thrax "Spirited away" has no religious connotations.

Comment: Doesn't "spirit" have some?

Comment: Kidnapping could also refer to stealing someone's baby goat.

Comment: I would prefer to use "Abduct" as "kid" is slang and more correctly refers to baby goats. Unless your baby goats have been stolen.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It is normal to use "kidnap" in a non-child context. It does not sound strange at all, and it is actually the [correct legal term for the crime](http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/kidnapping), which is not specific to children:

> The crime of unlawfully seizing and carrying away a person...

"Abducting" is a common synonym for "kidnapping".

Sometimes the "kid" in "kidnapping" is replaced by some other noun, as in "[dognapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dognapping)". This is often used seriously (as *dognapping* is) but may be slightly humorous in more bizarre or trivial circumstances, like [pignapping](http://www.baynews9.com/content/news/baynews9/news/article.html/content/news/articles/bn9/2014/9/24/_1_arrested_1_sought.html) or [lappynapping](http://www.hrwiki.org/wiki/Lappynapped!).

Comment: What about catnapping? :)

Comment: @Vixen Catnapping is usually used to mean a "cat nap" (to sleep), and not a "cat kidnap" (to abduct).

Comment: @ZekeSonxx 'Kitnapped', perhaps? :P

Comment: @ZekeSonxx: I know, I just found it amusing :)

Answer (score 7):

Yes. Though the etymology suggests that it is derived from "Kid"(might be because initially only kids were kidnapped), it is *generally* used to refer the act of taking someone illegally by force.

If it sounds wrong to you, you could use synonyms like "Abduct" or "held captive" or "held in captivity".

Comment: Etymonline [supports your hypothesis](http://etymonline.com/index.php?search=kidnap): *originally "steal children to provide servants and laborers in the American colonies."*

Answer (score 6):

The Wiktionary definition states:

> 1. (transitive) To seize and detain a **person** unlawfully; sometimes for ransom.
>
> <sub>Source: [Definition of “kidnap” on wiktionary.org](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kidnap)</sub>

Despite the origins, the word is commonly used in cases where adults are taken.

We can all hear “kid” when we say “kidnap” though, so sometimes people will make formations based on the “[-nap](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-nap#English)” suffix. Examples include “[dognap](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dognap)”, and “[catnap](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/catnap)”, (note that the latter might confuse people as the term is more common as a noun meaning a “brief, light sleep” or as an intransitive verb meaning “to take a catnap”). You can also form verbs like this on the fly: *Who cup-napped my favorite mug?*

The formal term is properly “kidnap” in the case of any person being abducted.